# Pivoting Data in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table as

| Start Date | sequence No | Count | Emp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| old | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-12-07 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| More | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| Total | 3 | 20 | 1 |
| old | 0 | 15 | 2 |
| 2020-12-07 | 1 | 20 | 2 |
| More | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| Total | 3 | 40 | 2 |

I require output as

| Emp_id | Old | 2020-12-07 | More | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15 | 4 | 20 |
| 2 | 15 | 20 | 5 | 40 |

Can someone please give me some idea or point in a direction on how can i achieve the desired output?

Comment: Try `CROSSTAB` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed list of values, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select emp_id
    max(count) filter(where start_date = 'old'       ) as val_old,
    max(count) filter(where start_date = '2020-12-07') as val_2020_12_07,
    max(count) filter(where start_date = 'More'      ) as val_more,
    max(count) filter(where start_date = 'Total'     ) as val_total
from mytable
group by emp_id
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but the values aren't fixed, the date in the start_date column will keep on getting changed as the week passes on. So I was hoping for a dynamic approach